# Possible to code timeframe visibility to a plot in Pine Script?

Tags: plot, pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am a complete noob to coding but I have a script with a lot of indicators in it. Like vwap, ema, sma. Now I can't figure out how to plot the vwap so it's only visible on 1-5 min timeframe and the MA's only visibile on the 30+ min chart. Is this possible?, because I rather have everything in one script then have three different and select the visibility in options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below function to get the resolution in minutes. Then plot the things you want to plot based on that.

```
f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

res_in_min = f_resInMinutes()
can_plot_ma = res_in_min >= 30
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try figure out your solution and test it.

Comment: Hey it worked @vitruvius 
Thanks again. 

Maybe not the prettiest coding but at least it's working...

plot(can_plot_ma ? ema5 : na, title="EMA 100", color= active5 ? emacol5 : na)